# Printed Array elements showing up as addresses?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, foreach, nested-loops

I have been trying to get the objects in my array to print out fully instead of what I think is their address in memory? I had a for each loop that printed out all of the elements, and it worked however, I really only need the top 3. So I chose to copy the top three elements to a second array to iterate through and print. instead of printing the top 3 it just displays a long list of addresses. this happens every time I run option to or three, and I can only run them after running option 1 once. Would someone, please instruct me on what I'm doing wrong?

```
    // Imports
import java.util.*;  
import java.io.*; 

class Player{

    public String first_name;
    public String last_name;
    public double attack; // attack stats
    public double block; // block stats

    // Creation of a constructor for player object. it takes a line which will be passed from scanner a later on.
    public Player(String first_name ,String last_name , double attack, double block){
        this.first_name = first_name;
        this.last_name = last_name;
        this.attack = attack;
        this.block = block;
    }


}


class VerdeVolleyball{
    // an array to hold all players
    static Player[] roster = new Player[20];
    // number of players on roster
    static int players_on_roster;

    // METHODS
    // 1) Open a roster, then the program should ask for the filename of the roster, then read the data from that file into an array. 

     public static void openRoster(){

        // prompt for roster name
       try{
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the roster:");
        String entry = input.nextLine();
        File file = new File(entry);

        // Scanner object to read each players info
        Scanner file_scanner = new Scanner(file);

        int index = 0;
        String line = null;

        while((file_scanner.hasNextLine())){
            //as long as it has a line set it to line and create a player from that line
            line = file_scanner.nextLine();
            String[] split = line.split(" ");
            String first_name = split[0];
            String last_name = split[1];
            double attack = Double.parseDouble(split[2]);
            double block = Double.parseDouble(split[3]); 

            Player player = new Player(first_name, last_name, attack, block);
            roster[index]= player;
            index++;
            players_on_roster++;
     }       
            file_scanner.close();

                System.out.println(players_on_roster + " players on roster.");

              }catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
                  System.out.println("File not found!");
                  e.printStackTrace();
                   }catch(NullPointerException e) { 
            System.out.print("NullPointerException Caught!"); 
        } 
    }

        //2) List top 3 attackers, then the program should determine and list the names and stats of the players with the top 3 attack stats.If the user tries to list the top attackers without first opening a roster file, then the program should respond with the error message "Please open a roster."

    public static void listTopAttackers(){
       try{ 
        for(int sort_iters = 0; sort_iters < players_on_roster; sort_iters++){
            for(int index = sort_iters+1; index < players_on_roster; index++){

                if(roster[index].attack < roster[index+1].attack){
                    // Swap to order
                    Player temp_holder = roster[index];
                    roster[index] = roster[index+1];
                    roster[index+1]  = temp_holder;

                    // create an array to store top 3
                    Player[] top_3_attack = new Player[3];
                    top_3_attack[0] = roster[0];
                    top_3_attack[1] = roster[1];
                    top_3_attack[2] = roster[2];

                    for(Object p : top_3_attack) {
                        Player player = (Player) p;
                        System.out.println(top_3_attack.toString());
                  }
            }
                    }
                          }
        }catch(NullPointerException e) { 
            System.out.print("NullPointerException Caught!"); 
             }
    }
        //3) List top 3 blockers, then the program should determine and list the names and stats of the players with the top 3 stats for blocks.If the user tries to list the top blockers without first opening a roster file, then the program should respond with the error message "Please open a roster."

    public static void listTopBlockers(){
        try{
         for(int sort_iters = 0;sort_iters < players_on_roster; sort_iters++){
            for(int index = sort_iters + 1; index < players_on_roster; index++){

                if(roster[index].block < roster[index+1].block){
                    // Swap to order
                    Player temp_holder = roster[index];
                    roster[index] = roster[index+1];
                    roster[index+1]  = temp_holder;

                    // create an array to store top 3
                    Player[] top_3_block = new Player[3];
                    top_3_block[0] = roster[0];
                    top_3_block[1] = roster[1];
                    top_3_block[2] = roster[2];

                    for(Object p : top_3_block) {
                        Player player = (Player) p;
                        System.out.println(top_3_block.toString());
                  }
            } 
                     }
                 }   
     }catch(NullPointerException e) { 
            System.out.print("NullPointerException Caught!");

        }
    }


        //4) Make and display scrimmage teams, then the program should divide the roster into 6-person scrimmage teams, and display the list of players on each team.If the user tries to make and display scrimmage teams without first opening a roster file, then the program should respond with the error message "Please open a roster.
  /*  public static void createTeams(Player p[],int count){
        // determined the number teams, with and without odd players
        remainder = roster.length % 6;
        int teams = (roster.length - remainder) / 6;

        //Array to store the team names
        String scrimmage_teams[] = new String[teams];

        for(int i = 0; i < teams; ir++){
            Scrimmage_teams[i = new String();
                    }

        listTopAttackers();
        for(int i = 0; i <teams;i++){
            int attackers = 0;
            int j = i;

            while(attackers <3 && j < roster.length){
                scrimmage_teams[i] = scrimmag_teams[i] + "\t" + roster[j].name
            } 
        }


   } */


   public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner selection_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String user_selection = null;

        do{
           //Menu
           System.out.println(""); 
           System.out.println("1) Open a roster");
           System.out.println("2) List top 3 attackers");
           System.out.println("3) List top 3 blockers");
           System.out.println("4) Make and display scrimmage teams");
           System.out.println("5) Quit");
           System.out.println("");

            //Read user option
            user_selection = selection_input.nextLine();
         if ( user_selection.equals("1")){
            openRoster(); 
        } else if (user_selection.equals("2")){
            listTopAttackers();
        } else if (user_selection.equals("3")){
            listTopBlockers();
       //}else if (user_selection.equals("4")){
            // makeTeams();   */
        } else if (user_selection.equals("5")){
            System.out.println("Quitting Program");
            System. exit(0);
        } else{
               System.out.println("Please choose from the given options");
        }        
            }while(true);

        } 


              }// class end
```

Comment: Just override & implement a `toString(): String` method for your `Player` class. The `toString()` method currently uses the one defined in `Object` and that one prints out a unique code.

Comment: Also: get rid of the `catch (NullPointerException...)` clauses.  Let the NPEs propagate.  If your application is generating NPEs, that is a bug.  You need to see the stacktrace so that you can track down the cause of the exception and fix the bug.  Squashing the exception is hiding the bug under the carpet.

Answer (score 0):

**Root Cause:**

The implementation of toString() method in Object class would return you 'ClassName@id' format value.

**Solution:**

You just need to override your toString() method in your desired class(i.e. Player class).

For instance you can try the below code, the final implementation would depend on your use case requirement:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.first_name+" "+this.last_name+" | "+this.attack+" | "+this.block;
 }
```